# Firebase real-time efficiency question: How to set up listeners for a chat app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat app using Firebase as a realtime database and React Native. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to set up the listener for chat messages from Firebase in terms of minimizing read operations and transferring data. Here is my data structure:

```
- messages
  - chatId
    - messageId
      - sentBy
      - timestamp
      - text
```

As I see it I have 2 options, either `ref.on("child_added)` or `ref.on("value")`

If I use `ref.on("child_added")`, the advantage is that when a new message is sent then only the newest message is retrieved. The problem though is that when the conversation is loaded the `read` operation is called for each message in the chat. If a conversation is hundreds of messages long, then that's hundreds of `read` operations.

The other option is to use `ref.on("value")`. The problem here is that on every new message added, the entire conversation is resent instead of just the most recent message. The advantage is that when the conversation is loaded, only one `read` operation is called to transfer the entire conversation to the screen.

I want some combination of the two of these in which when the conversation is loaded, there is one `read` operation that brings the entire contents of the conversation, AND when a new child node is added (a new message) *only* that message is transmitted to the listener. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no difference between the wire traffic for a `value` listener and `child_` listeners on the same location/query. If you check the Network tab of your browser, you can see exactly what is sent retrieved, and you'll see that it's exactly the same between the listener types.

The difference between `value` and `child_*` events is purely made client-side to make it easier for you to update the UI. In fact, even when you attach both `value` and `child_*` listeners to the same query/location, Firebase will only retrieve the data only once.

The common way to do what you want is to attach both `child_*` and `value` listeners to the query/location. Since the `value` listener is guaranteed to be fired last, you can use that fact to detect when the initial load is done.

Something like:

```
var chatRef = firebase.database().ref("messages/chatId");
var initialLoadDone = false;
chatRef.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
  if (initialLoadDone) {
    ...
  }
});
chatRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((messageSnapshot) => {
    ...
  });
  initialLoadDone = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Use Firestore. It maintains a cache of your data and efficiently handles such scenarios.

---

You can use `ref.once('value')` to get current nodes **only once** and then `ref.on('child_added')` for subsequent additions. [More performance notes.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize#efficient-listeners)

**Edit:** I believe Firebase Database handles this efficiently by just `ref.on('value')`. On checking the network tab after adding a new node to my database, I notified the amount of data that got transferred was very low. This might mean that firebase by default caches your previous data. Would recommend you to look at your network tab and take decisions as such or wait from someone from their team show directions.

Comment: The problem is when `ref.on("child_added")` is called it first grabs all current child nodes one at a time (which could be a hundred reads) and only after that does it grab subsequent additions. Is there a way to prevent that first action?

Comment: use where clause for timestamp above a `cursorTimestamp`. This `cursorTimestamp` is when your `value` query ran.